# Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced ansible k8s

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-inventory

My k8s.yaml inventory file is:

```yaml
plugin: k8s

connections:

- kubeconfig: '/Users/user1/Documents/Learning/ansible/kubeconfig.test.yaml'

context: 'user1@testeks.us-east-1.eksctl.io'
```

ansible playbook:

test_new.yml

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

tasks:

- name: Create a k8s namespace

k8s:

name: testing3

api_version: v1

kind: Namespace

state: present
```

Looks like the ansibleplaybook command is not picking up the inventory k8s.yaml.Also I am not sure why I am getting Warning invalid characters {'-' in group name warnings.

Please let me know if the above inventory file and ansible playbook files look good or are there anything I am missing?

```sh
ansible-playbook -vvvv -i k8s.yaml -vvv ./test_new.yml
No config file found; using defaults

setting up inventory plugins

host_list declined parsing /Users/user1/Documents/Learning/ansible/k8s.yaml as it did not pass its verify_file() method

script declined parsing /Users/user1/Documents/Learning/ansible/k8s.yaml as it did not pass its verify_file() method

Not replacing invalid character(s) "{'-', '9'}" in group name (909676E2B4F81625BF5994625D3353C9-yl4-us-east-1-eks-amazonaws-com)

[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details

Not replacing invalid character(s) "{'-'}" in group name (namespace_add-ons)

Not replacing invalid character(s) "{'-'}" in group name (namespace_add-ons_pods)

Not replacing invalid character(s) "{'.', '/', '-'}" in group name (label_app.kubernetes.io/instance_aws-cluster-autoscaler)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you got that you need the Kubernetes parameters specified in your inventory file. If you look at the [k8s module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html) it says that `kubeconfig` and `context` are specified in the playbook or as environment variables.

Your [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) should look something like this:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    host.where.can.access.the.kubeapiserver.com:
```

Then your playbook:

```yaml
- name: Create a k8s namespace
  k8s:
    name: testing3
    api_version: v1
    kind: Namespace
    state: present
    kubeconfig: '/Users/user1/Documents/Learning/ansible/kubeconfig.test.yaml'  this can replaced by the K8S_AUTH_KUBECONFIG env variable
    context: 'user1@testeks.us-east-1.eksctl.io'   this can replaced by the K8S_AUTH_CONTEXT env variable
```

Comment: I got that from the example here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/k8s.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the formatting of your post, it looks like your inventory file contains improper syntax. It should look like this:

```
plugin: k8s
connections:
  - kubeconfig: '/Users/user1/Documents/Learning/ansible/kubeconfig.test.yaml'
    context: 'user1@testeks.us-east-1.eksctl.io'
```

Remember that spaces are important.

For deprecation warnings, be sure to read up on these issues:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/56930
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/issues/4830

Usage of hyphens in inventory group names was deprecated in Ansible 2.8 due to Python parser errors when using dot syntax. Auto-transformation can be disabled by adding `force_valid_group_names = never` to your Ansible config file. Similarly, deprecation warnings can be suppressed by adding `deprecation_warnings = False` though this is not recommended.